# Can I protect a file in SVN so that only certain users can edit6 a directory or view a file?

Tags: svn

So, I have a secret sauce configuration file that I only want certain users to be able to see in SVN.  Or that I only want certain users to have the ability to edit.  But I still want it in SVN so that it's safe and can be retrieved in case of server downtime.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with Path-Based Authorization (requires Apache or svnserve), but only to the directory level. You'd have to put your super secret file in its own directory, then lock down the access there.

See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.perdir & http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html

Answer (score 1):

You can, but to completely hide a file, you need to configure it from the server end. How you do it depends upon whether you're using the built-in `svnserve` server or Apache `httpd`.

I recommend that you put your *secret sauce* stuff in a separate folder near the root of your repository, and then protect that folder.

See the on line manual on [server configuration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.html) and the section of on access for [`svnserve`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.auth) or [`http`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.perdir), depending how your server is setup.